# What should I consider in my situation to decrease the val_loss?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

[image]

I am new in cnn, and I wanted to know how may I improve my model? Augmentation is already done. Thanks in advance.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', strides=(1,1), 
                 padding='same', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', strides=(1,1),
                 padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', strides=(1,1),
                 padding='same'))
#model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', strides=(1,1), 
 #            padding='same'))                 
#model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))#AveragePooling2D
model.add(AveragePooling2D(2,2))#AveragePooling2D

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))    
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
#opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer= "Adam",
              metrics=\['acc'\] )][1]][1]

history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=32, 
      shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1
      callbacks = [checkpoint])
```

```
Epoch 00140: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
Epoch 141/150
28620/28620 [==============================] - 37s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1654 - acc: 0.9401 - val_loss: 0.2388 - val_acc: 0.9267

Epoch 00141: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
Epoch 142/150
28620/28620 [==============================] - 38s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1314 - acc: 0.9516 - val_loss: 0.2728 - val_acc: 0.9091

Epoch 00142: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
Epoch 143/150
28620/28620 [==============================] - 37s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1425 - acc: 0.9476 - val_loss: 0.2439 - val_acc: 0.9242

Epoch 00143: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
Epoch 144/150
28620/28620 [==============================] - 37s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1434 - acc: 0.9473 - val_loss: 0.3709 - val_acc: 0.8824

Epoch 00144: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
Epoch 145/150
28620/28620 [==============================] - 37s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1483 - acc: 0.9468 - val_loss: 0.2544 - val_acc: 0.9208

Epoch 00145: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
Epoch 146/150
28620/28620 [==============================] - 35s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1366 - acc: 0.9501 - val_loss: 0.2872 - val_acc: 0.9110

Epoch 00146: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
Epoch 147/150
28620/28620 [==============================] - 36s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1476 - acc: 0.9465 - val_loss: 0.3147 - val_acc: 0.9013

Epoch 00147: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
Epoch 148/150
28620/28620 [==============================] - 36s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1391 - acc: 0.9486 - val_loss: 0.2838 - val_acc: 0.9069

Epoch 00148: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
Epoch 149/150
28620/28620 [==============================] - 35s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1392 - acc: 0.9486 - val_loss: 0.2541 - val_acc: 0.9211

Epoch 00149: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
Epoch 150/150
28620/28620 [==============================] - 37s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1401 - acc: 0.9489 - val_loss: 0.2213 - val_acc: 0.9308

Epoch 00150: val_acc did not improve from 0.93082
```

Comment: Try shuffling your data

Comment: I forgot to put the fit part

Comment: you could have also provided at least the last lines of the training so we can see the train and validation accuracies.. for now you can go for more epochs.. maybe 300 to see

Comment: I think it will not helpif I will increase the number of epochs.